# Scala Apriori Algorithm : if first index value is same, then Generate Three item set from two items set list

Tags: scala, combinations, apriori

i want this answer

```
if Input list is >> List( List("A","B"),List("A","C"),List("B","C"),List("B","D"))

Output should be >> List(List("A", "B","C"),List("B","C","D"))
```

i think it should be done as following>> all indices having first element same are grouped e.g if first element is `"A"` then group will be `("A","B","B","C").distinct = ("A","B","C")`

Comment: From where comes the `C` in the first group?

Comment: it was var a=List("A","B","C","D")  i generated combinations of this list as a.combinations(2)

Comment: I mean in the result.

Comment: List("A","B") and List("A","C") has first elements same, so they can merge to generate three itemset, List("A","B")+List("A","C")= List("A","C","A","B").distinct= List(A","B","C")

Comment: IF var a=List(A,B,C,D) THEN TWO itemset combinations will be a.combinations(2) List(List(A,B)List(A,C),List(A,D),List(B,C),List(B,D), List(C,D))
NOW all lists having first element same can be merge/ union
as List(A,B),List(A,c),List(A,D) have first element same so possible three itemset combinations  will be List(A,B,C) AND List(A,B,D) AND List(A,C,D)

Comment: Is this what you are after? `a.combinations(2).toList.groupBy(_.head).mapValues(_.flatten.distinct.combinations(3).toList).valuesIterator.flatten.toList` That seems to work but has a very bad complexity.

Comment: Please edit the question to fully reflect the problem instead of explaining in comments. see [how to ask](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)